# Let $X_1, X_2$ be independent random variables, then $\mathbb{E}[X_1]$ increases implies $\mathbb{E}[\max(X_1,X_2)]$ increases?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory

Suppose I have independent random variables $X_1,X_2$ taking values on $[0,1]$. $X_1$ follows a cdf $P_1(x)$ and $X_2$ follows a pdf $P_2(x)$. Then
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X_1] = \int_0^1 xdP_1(x) = \int_0^1 xP'_1(x)dx
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[\max(X_1,X_2)] = \int_0^1 xd(P_1(x)P_2(x)) = \int_0^1 x(P_1(x)P'_2(x) + P'_1(x)P_2(x))dx
\end{equation}
Now, suppose that I replace the distribution for $X_1$ by $\tilde{P}_1$ with higher $\mathbb{E}[X_1]$. Is it true that $\mathbb{E}[\max(X_1,X_2)]$ also increase? i.e.
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 xd\tilde{P}_1(x) \geq \int_0^1 xdP_1(x) \implies \int_0^1 xd(\tilde{P}_1(x)P_2(x)) \geq \int_0^1 xd(P_1(x)P_2(x))?
\end{equation}
How do I show this? Thanks!

Comment: Just consider the three following independent rvs: $X_1\sim U[0,1/3],X_2\sim U[2/3,1],X_1'\sim U[1/3,2/3]$.

Comment: Thank you! that's a good point. But $>$ in the question was meant to be $\geq$. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X_1\sim \textrm{Bernoulli}(1/10)$ and $X_2 \sim U[1/2,1]$. Then $E[X_1]=1/10$ and
$$E[\max(X_1,X_2)]=\frac{1}{10}+\frac{3}{4}\frac{9}{10}=\frac{31}{40}>\frac{3}{4}$$
Now let $X_1'\sim U[0,1/2]$. Then $E[X_1']=1/4$ but $E[\max(X_1',X_2)]=E[X_2]=3/4$.

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED]
Consider $X_1 = -2$ with probability $1/2$ and $1$ with probability $1/2$ (the original distribution), $\tilde{X_1} = -1$ with probability $1/2+\epsilon$ and $1$ with probability $1/2-\epsilon$ (the new distribution) where $1/2 > \epsilon > 0$, while  $X_2 = 0$ with probability $1$. Then
$$\mathbb E[\tilde{X_1}] = -2\epsilon > -1/2 = \mathbb E[X_1]$$ but
$$\mathbb E[\max(X_1, X_2)] = 1/2 > 1/2 - \epsilon = \mathbb E[\max(\tilde{X_1}, X_2)]$$

Comment: You have taken a specific case, the OP has a general question isn't it?

Comment: A specific counterexample shows that the answer to a general question is no.

Comment: The last line of your example sort of supports OP's hypothesis?

Comment: Hello @RobertIsrael, I think OP has specified the range of the rvs also

Comment: @KB Oops: fixed.

Comment: @Snoop: translate and scale to put them in that range.